# Log Errors from twig template

Tags: craft2

I need to log flash messages from `craft.session.getFlashes` to a error log file from a particular twig template in Craft 2. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a plugin (https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/introduction.html,  https://pluginfactory.io/)
2. Create a Variable class with a log function (https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/variables.html)
3. Pass data from getFlashes to your function from within the template like e.g. `craft.yourPluginName.yourVariableFunctionName(craft.session.getFlashes)`

Tip: Use YourPluginName::log('blabla' . $string); to log anything to /storage/runtime/logs/yourpluginname.log from within your Plugin